# Assigning a number to each level in a tree

Tags: python, tree

I'm trying to make a method *set_number* which takes a value and sets self.number of the first level in a tree to that given value and the self.number of the next level in a tree to the previous value(self.number) + 1, and so fourth.

And here's what I've come up with so far:

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, item, left=None, right=None):

        self.item = item
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        self.number = 0

    def set_number(self, value):

        if self.left == None and self.right == None:
            self.number = value
        elif self.left:
            self.number = max(self.number, self.left.set_number(value + 1))
        elif self.right:
            self.number = max(self.number, self.right.set_number(value + 1))
        return self.number
```

An example of what I mean:

example tree:

```
                  5
                /  \
              2      6

tree = Node(5, Node(2), Node(6))
tree.set_number(2)
```

what .set_number(2) does to that tree:

```
                  5   <- sets self.number to the given value in this case 2
                /  \
              2      6 <- sets self.number to the previous value + 1, in this case 2 + 1 = 3.
```

therefore it should return 3 since the last change to self.number was setting it to 3. My code does that fine.

another example:

```
                  4
                /  \
              2      6
            /  \    / \
           1    3  5   7

tree = Node(5, Node(2, Node(1), Node(3)), Node(6, Node(5), Node(7)))
tree.set_number(5)
```

what .set_number(5) does to that tree:

```
                  4  <- sets self.number to the given value, in this case 5
                /  \
              2      6  <- sets self.number to the previous self.number value + 1, in this case 5+1=6
            /  \    / \
           1    3  5   7 <- sets self.number to the previous self.number value + 1, in this case 6+1=7
```

therefore it should return 7 since the last change to self.number was setting it to 7. My code does that fine.

But here is where my code seems to fail:

```
                  4
                /  \
              2      6
            /  \    / \
           1    3  5   7
                        \
                         8     

tree = Node(5, Node(2, Node(1), Node(3)), Node(6, Node(5), Node(7, None, Node(8))))
tree.set_number(1)
```

It should return 4 since it sets the first level to 1, the second to 2, the third to 3 and the fourth to 4, however 3 in being returned instead of 4. I was wondering if anyone can help me figure out where I went wrong and what change I need to make in order to fix this issue.

Comment: Changing your *elif* s to *if* s might help. I'm not sure what the state of the tree after *set_number()* should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if a node has both a left and right child? In your code, you have:

```
if self.left == None and self.right == None:
    ...
elif self.left:
    ...
elif self.right:
    ...
```

But you'll note that if there if a left child and right child, the `elif self.left` block will execute, but the `elif self.right` block will not. Changing it to this should help:

```
if self.left == None and self.right == None:
    ...
else
    if self.left:
        ...
    if self.right:
        ...
```